# Why is my gas water heater not getting as hot since I added new lines to a new shower

Tags: water-heater

I recently added a new bathroom. New shower and vanity. I tied in and added one more 8ft run of pipe, hot and cold, to supply this bathroom.  All the fittings are good and I can't see any obvious problems.  Now that everything is done, my gas water heater isn't getting as hot as it did before. Coincidence or could I have done something to make this happen

Comment: Is it the water heater not getting hot(less hot at all faucets/taps) or just the new line?  New extra line should not affect heater, might take a bit longer for hot water to come out of tap, but that is all.

Comment: Do you have hot water issues at all the taps or just the new ones?

Comment: Is it isolated ..

Comment: Sounds like you accidentally bumped the dial on your water heater or forgot to turn the gas back on. Try turning it up and see if you notice a difference.

Comment: So, all fixtures are less hot or just that new bathroom? Maybe your water heater broke during the renovation.

Comment: Do you mean the shower outlet is not as hot ?

Comment: Yes, please revise to clarify with supporting details. It's not clear what you've observed or what has changed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way adding 8' of pipe will affect your WH. Like MonkeyZeus said, check your settings, make sure it's not been changed.   To be more objective in your diagnosis, use a food thermometer and check various faucets after letting the hot water run for a while. A normal temp would be about 120 degrees F, (about 50 degrees C). Also, if you have any temp mixing valves, they might have been affected (IE: slightly clogged by debris) when you had the water turned off.

Comment: "There is no way adding 8' of pipe will affect your WH." - except to royally screw it up and not be aware of your mistake.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus LOL at your comment. I can't imagine how someone could "royally screw it up" on such a simple install. Maybe if a HW recirc line is involved, I could imagine something.  Recently I helped a friend do a R&R on a WH with re-circ. We took pics before and when putting it back together, I realized the re-circ pump was installed backwards, injecting cold water into the HW supply. I asked him if he had temp problems in the shower, etc. and said yes, it's always been that way, varies a lot. So I'm thinking CRAP, this was originally installed by a licensed plumber.

Comment: Glad I could give you a chuckle! Maybe a preface is worthy: "Assuming a correct install, there is no way adding 8' of pipe will affect your WH."

Comment: @MonkeyZeus   Risking getting snipped here for an extended conversation in comments...love your alternate intro!   Many times I just SMH at the questions, but that's what we're here for. Take care.

Comment: "I helped a friend do a R&R on a WH" Rest & Relaxation? I know your comment was getting long, but what's an "R&R" in this context?

Comment: @FreeMan  Yeah, I can be a blabbermouth at times!  I thought R&R was commonly used for Remove & Replace.   Thanks for asking.

Comment: No worries! I kinda figured that, but it's always good to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way by adding a hot water outlet, to reduce the WH set temperature.

Unless you changed the set, or emptied the WH to connect the extra pipe. Use the pressure release to let the trapped air out.

Possibly your shower mixer valve is not working properly.